# Are there SSL behaviour changes in Delphi 11?

Tags: delphi, websocket, openssl, indy

For months, I have used the IdWebSocketSimpleClient unit with Delphi 10.3 provided [here](https://github.com/adaloveless/commonx/blob/master/IdWebsocketSimpleClient.pas) to setup a Websocket connection to the discord gateway API. Now, that I changed to Delphi 11, the same code shows another behaviour.

Previously, the component connected to the server, initiated an HTTP Upgrade to a websocket connection, received the 101 - switching protocols response and started to communicate. Now, with Delphi 11, I receive a 400 - Bad request. The inner error message shows "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port". In both scenarios, the same OpenSSL dll files are sitting in the applications executable folder and an TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component is used.

At this point, I am really confused why this is happening, as the programs code hasn't been changed. This makes me wonder if there have been any behaviour changes to the indy units involved. I have no clue where to even start my investigation. Can someone help?

Comment: But offhand, I do not see any code in `IdWebSocketSimpleClient.pas` attempting to initiate an SSL/TLS handshake at all. It appears to *assume* that `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.PassThrough` is set to `False` *before* `Connect()` is called, rather than *forcing* it to `False` when connecting to a secure URL. It is certainly not being set to `False` for an auto-created `SSLIOHandler`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the PassTrough actually did the trick! How comes it is required in Delphi 11, but not in Delphi 10.3 - any idea?

Comment: I have posted an answer explaining what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi 10.3 was released in late 2018.  There was a change made to the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` class in late 2019, to fix a bug where its `PassThrough` property was being initialized to `False` when it should have been initialized to `True` instead (which is now the current behavior).

So, that could easily account for the behavior you are seeing, as the error message is complaining about an unsecured HTTP message being sent to a secure HTTPS port (because `PassThrough` is likely `True`).

That change did not affect most Indy components, as internally they explicitly set `PassThrough` as needed (typically based on a `UseTLS` property, or a specific URL protocol/port being requested).  But, the change does affect end-user code that uses `TIdTCPClient` directly (as this WebSocket code is doing).  In that case, the user is (and always has been) responsible for setting `PassThrough` as they need, but this WebSocket code is not doing that.  When connecting to a secure URL, it *assumes* that `PassThrough` has been set to `False` by the user before `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.Connect()` is called, rather than *forcing* it to `False`.  And `PassThrough` is certainly not being set to `False` if `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient` needs to auto-create its own `SSLIOHandler` object.

`TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.Connect()` *should* internally be setting `PassThrough := not lSecure;` before calling `inherited Connect`.  I have reported this as a bug to the author for you:

[#10: TIdSimpleWebSocketClient TLS error - 400 Bad request, the plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port](https://github.com/adaloveless/commonx/issues/10)

In the meantime, until the author fixes this bug, you can simply assign your own `SSLIOHandler` component to the `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.IOHandler` property and set it to `PassThrough=False` before calling `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.Connect()` with a `wss:` URL.